# Google Apps Scripts: Using UrlFetchApp for sites that require authentication

Tags: wordpress, authentication, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I would like to fetch an URL that requires an authentication, like the admin page of Wordpress using Google Apps Script, UrlFetch (anything else is fine if its something in Apps Script.)

There seems to be solution if it is a basic auth though.
Is that possible for Wordpress?

Answer (score -1):

For WordPress, you can install the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) plugin and then use Basic Auth + UrlFetch to get your data into Apps Script. This, I think, is the ideal solution.

If you want it for anyother website, you should mention it in the question. In generak, yes, Basic Auth is the solution.